# write code that prints out values in order from two seperate list

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, counter

I have list

```py
num1 = [1, 3, 5]
num2 = [2, 4, 6]
```

I need to print all integers in both list from 1 to 6 in order with out using sort or append. I must use a for loop and a counter. the counter should be used as a pointer.

I have tried different ways of using x in the for loop but cant seem to get a value of x that will point to each specific index

```py
x=0
for num in num1: 
    if (num1 + num2)[x] > num:
        print num
    elif (num1 + num2)[x] < num:
        print num[x]
    else: x = x + 1
```

I expect my output to be

```py
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

but I continue to get error messages

Comment: I don't get an error message when I run your code, but I don't get an output either. A couple problems to note: your `for` loop will only have 3 iterations, and your conditions in the conditional statements will never be true since `(num1 + num2)[x]` is always equal to `num`.

Comment: Instead of using a `for` loop, a `while` loop may be appropriate here. But why are you avoiding `sort` and `append`?

Comment: on this problem our professor wants us to specifically use a for loop. and to avoid sort and append as it would be an easy solve. he gave us hints to use a loop counter and use the counter as a pointer.

Comment: num1 = [1, 3, 5]
num2 = [2, 4, 6]
num3 = num1 + num2
x = 0

#write code that prints out values in order from both list
# can nnot use sort or append
for num in num3:
    if num1[x] > x:
        x = num1[x]
    elif num1[x] < x:
        x = num2[x]
    else:
        x = x + 1
   
print x                                                                              Ive tried this as well but it hasn't worked for me

Comment: Are the lists always in order like that? For instance, would you ever have `num1 = [1, 5, 3]` and `num2 = [6, 2, 4]`?

Comment: yeah the numbers can be random but for each list but I have to write a for loop that will order them using an index counter as a pointer. the numbers have to appear in order form smallest to biggest and he wont accept it if we use append or sort.

Comment: I would look at [common sorting algorithms](https://medium.com/@george.seif94/a-tour-of-the-top-5-sorting-algorithms-with-python-code-43ea9aa02889) to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

Though not explicitly mentioned, I believe the assumption here is that both the lists num1 and num2 are already sorted. With that assumption in place, one way to achieve this is to walk both the lists simultaneously and keep printing the smaller value. See the sample below.

```
num1 = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19]
num2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

l = num1
oth = num2
if len(num2) > len(num1):
    l = num2
    oth = num1
m = len(l)

i = 0
j = 0
while i < m:
    if j >= len(oth) or l[i] < oth[j]:
        print(l[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        print(oth[j])
        j += 1

while j < len(oth):
    print(oth[j])
    j += 1
```